# Como puedo instalar donet en elementary os (GNU/Linux)?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core

Como puedo instalar .Net Core en elementary os (GNU/Linux)? He probado de la misma forma que ubuntu 16.04 ya que esta montado sobre este sistema pero cuando escribo en la terminal (luego de probar los las lineas de la pagina de micrasoft):

> sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-2.0.0

me da que hay paquetes que no pueden ser instalados, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder instalar .NET, deberá registrar la clave de Microsoft, registrar el repositorio del producto e instalar las dependencias requeridas.

Abra una terminal y ejecute los siguientes comandos:

```
$- wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
$- sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

Instalar .NET SDK
Actualice los productos disponibles para la instalación, luego instale .NET SDK.

En la terminal, ejecute los siguientes comandos:

```
$- sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https 
$- sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1
```

Espero ser ayuda.

Comment: Para colaborar con la respuesta, en un post coloqué imágenes http://fredyfx.com/post/instalando-dotnet-core-en-ubuntu/ Saludos :D